# Performance Benchmarking of Worklight apps

Tags: benchmarking, ibm-mobilefirst, performance-testing

All,

Is there any tool out there to measure the performance of the Worklight apps with respect to UI navigation and backend(Adapter) connectivity. Is there any performance benchmarks of  Worklight apps on real device for a specific use case? What are the various ways we can capture/sense the performance of a Worklight app on real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment.

I would highly encourage you to write one and put it on [Github](http://github.com/). I'm sure it would help many people in your situation.

You can also try existing tools (not specific to Worklight) to [benchmark servers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) and [clients](http://benchmarkjs.com/).